# Fastest method to store grid position in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I want to implement an algorithm, similar to BFS, using cells on a large NxN grid as graph nodes.
What way of storing the grid (x,y) positions would lead to the best performance?

1. Using an array [x,y], which means JS must create an object, references to it etc.
2. Using a pairing function like [ElegantPairing](http://szudzik.com/ElegantPairing.pdf) to produce a single integer. This would lead to many extra mathematical operations being executed.
3. Using a string (e.g. "12,13"), which would mean additional overhead parsing and generating the string
4. Another method I have not thought of.

Essentially, how efficient is JS in implementing array operations for many small arrays - and is it worth the computational overhead to convert and store the grid points in a value-type variable instead?

I will likely benchmark this myself later, but I would like to know if there is any theoretical reasoning which would make one of these answers preferable, based on how JS implements arrays internally and how performant it is.

Comment: What prevents you from benchmarking this yourself?

Comment: JavaScript, as a language, does not have performance characteristics. It all depends on the engine you run your code on.

Comment: This will be running on the V8 engine exclusively, if that's any help.